# Python unable to move directories using shutil

Tags: python, shutil, pathlib

I'm trying to write a script where it will move a directory (containing images to be processed) into another dedicated working directory (within the project folder) by using `shutil.move()`.
However, my Python script keeps on failing to achieve this by throwing an `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Desktop/Captured\\ Images'` exception.

The target directory is being perfectly recognised so that's not the issue.

I'm currently using macOS to develop this script, and using standard BASH.

This is how I input the path of the source directory (by dragging the folder into the terminal): `/Users/user/Desktop/Captured\ Images`.

This is how Python interprets the source directory: `/Users/user/Desktop/Captured\\ Images`.

The script works perfectly when I modify the source path to: `/Users/user/Desktop/Captured Images`.

I've also tried using the Pathlib Module to prevent file separator issues, but that also didn't work.

I know for sure that what's causing the problem is the `\` within the file path since the folder is named 'Captured Images' with a space between it, thus `Captured\ Images`.

Here's the following source code:

```
move_directory(input("Please Input The Directory Of The Captured Images You Would Like To Import: "))   

def move_directory(source_directory):
    try:
        shutil.move(source_directory, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/Captured Images/Source Images')
    except OSError as errorMessage:
        print("Failed To Move Directory: {0}".format(errorMessage))
```

**Update 1:**

I've just tried to move the directories by using `subprocess.run(["mv", ...])` and it worked, so now I see that it's not how the script is taking in the input, but a problem between the path input and `shutil.move()`.

Comment: There are some strange things happening with \ and /. Which os are you using? Windows uses \ while others use / as the folder separator.

Comment: I'm using macOS right now, and yes I'm aware of the \ and / separators. The thing is the folder contains a space in its name 'Captured Images' and I've created that folder just as a test, so it's not like I'm working cross OSs.

Comment: I've tried with both regular input() as well as raw input

Comment: @Marc could you copy exactly what you're entering?

Comment: @DemianWolf I'm not entering anything manually per-se, I'm simply dragging and dropping the folder into the terminal and then hit enter

Comment: @Marc What exactly leads to the error? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Marc I see. Then the problem depends on the OS (Linux/Mac OS etc.) you're using, file manager you're using, and the terminal and its features. You should clarify your question.